# Add a CLR fuction with an array of parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I would like to create a CLR function for SQL in C# then I can add the assembly to SQL the code will be like the next lines but I'm not sure if it is allowed.

```
[SqlFunction()]

public static SqlString method(params object[] parameters)
{

 // here the logic

}
```

In other words I would like to create a function like the SQL function `CONCAT` that should allow any number of parameters, example :

```
concat('test1','test2','test3','test4')
```

Or :

```
concat('test1','test2','test3','test4','test5','test6'..etc)
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: you have declared the function correctly. [refer to this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) as how to call this method.

Comment: Do you want to invoke the dll from SQL?

Comment: I already add the function to  CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction(@param1 nvarchar)

Comment: I already add the assembly to SQL 
what I need is to add the function to sql the sintaxt is